# Symfony Custom type deprecation notice

Tags: forms, symfony

We're currently updating our symfony 2.7 project to 3.*, and we're at the point of clearing deprecations at 2.8 version.

So I've keep getting deprecation notice

```
Passing type instances to FormBuilder::add(), Form::add() or the FormFactory is deprecated since version 2.8 and will not be supported in 3.0. Use the fully-qualified type class name instead (******\AutoBundle\Form\Type\ChoiceNVType)
```

ChoiceNVType is our custom type which we used so far like this:

```
$form->add('model', new ChoiceNVType(), array(
                'choices' => array(),
                'required' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Something',
                ));
```

Now we want to fix all deprecation notices but I have no idea how to do that with custom type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message clearly says you have to use FQN instead of an instance:

```
$form->add('model', '******\AutoBundle\Form\Type\ChoiceNVType', array(
                'choices' => array(),
                'required' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Something',
                ));
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it, the worst thing is I've tried earlier, and it actually didn't work. Thanks! :)

Comment: You could also write `ChoiceNVType::class` => makes it more readable IMHO